# How to index JSON by value name in python

Tags: python, json

Let's say I pull JSON daily and after some initial indexing, what I have looks like this:

```
[{'CategoryId': 493, 'name': 'foo'},
 {'CategoryId': 735, 'name': 'bar'},
 {'CategoryId': 988, 'name': 'baz'},
 {'CategoryId': 1024, 'name': 'foo_foo'},
 {'CategoryId': 729, 'name': 'foo_bar'},
 {'CategoryId': 743, 'name': 'foo_baz',
 {...}
]
```

And I want to access the dict where `name` is `foo_baz`.

Here is what I do now (ignore the `[...]` as they are just initial indexing I do to get to this point and is besides the point of the question):

```
(json.loads(response.text)[...][...][5])
```

Now this works... most of the time. Occasionally, there will be additional `CategoryId` that screws up my indexing, like so:

```
[{'CategoryId': 493, 'name': 'foo'},
 {'CategoryId': 735, 'name': 'bar'},
 {'CategoryId': 988, 'name': 'baz'},
 {'CategoryId': 1024, 'name': 'foo_foo'},
 {'CategoryId': 729, 'name': 'foo_bar'},
 {'CategoryId': 522, 'name': 'new_cat'},
 {'CategoryId': 743, 'name': 'foo_baz',
 {...}
]
```

This now ruins my indexing thanks to `new_cat`. What I have been doing is just implementing a try except, but this becomes un-pythonic very quickly:

```
try:
  lists = (json.loads(response.text)[...][...][5])
except KeyError:
  lists = (json.loads(response.text)[...][...][6])
  ...
```

So, my question is, is there a way I can just index this json based on the value of name? something like:

```
(json.loads(response.text)[...][...][function where name is equal to 'foo_baz'])
```

Comment: First, stop thinking about JSON.  Just do the `json.loads` one time and store it in a variable.  Then, you have a normal Python data structure.  Once you have a simple list of dicts, what you want is `x = [d for d in data if data['name'] == 'foo_baz'][0]`.  An even better plan might be to convert this to a dictionary with `name` as the key.

Comment: Could there be more than one occurrence of 'foo_baz'? If there's only one then you might as well enumerate the list of dictionaries and break early once (if) you find a match. Constructing a new dictionary just to do a lookup (which only works anyway if there's no repetition) could be unnecessarily expensive

Comment: This really has nothing to do with JSON (btw: none of your question contains any JSON!) but everything with how to use Python's data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do multiple lookups, I recommend:

```
lookup = {d['name']: d['CategoryId'] for d in data}
```

Now you can do `lookup['foo_baz']`.  And if there's really more data you haven't shown us, you can store the whole dict:

```
lookup = {d['name']: d for d in data}
```

Now you can do `lookup['foo_baz']['CategoryId']`.

Comment: Sorry, poor phrasing on my part. I don't just want the CategoryId where name is foo_baz, I want the entire dictionary where name is foo_baz, as there are more key value pairs that are unique to foo_baz that I want to access

Comment: just added a conditional to your provided list comprehension [d for d in data if d['name'] == 'foo_baz']. Marked as correct.

Comment: My second example there does what you describe -- it saves the whole dict.